# Rouché's Theorem Application

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to use Rouché's theorem to find the number of roots of the function $f(z)=z^5+3z^4+9z^3+10$ on $\vert z\vert<2$. I know that the answer is $3$, but I have been unsuccessful in proving it. I've tried nearly every combination of the components of $f$ which also have $3$ roots, applying the theorem up to $3$ times, but to no avail. I've even resorted to trying unrelated polynomials, but there's a lot of those! A hint would surely benefit my sanity.

Comment: Try $9z^3+10$ & $z^5+3z^4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the geometric sequence $1,3,9$ in the leading coefficients into account, multiply with $(z-3)$ to get
$$
g(z)=(z-3)f(z)=z^6-27z^3+10z-30
$$
which has the same number of roots inside the disk $|z|<2$. Now
$$
g(2w)=64w^6-216w^3+20w-30
$$
on $|w|=1$ has clearly the third order term as the dominating one.