# Zeros of $f(z) = z^5+3z^4+9z^3+10$ in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, rouches-theorem

> Show that $f(z) = z^5+3z^4+9z^3+10$ has $2$ zeros in the unit disk

I'm  trying to use Rouche's theorem.

So I tried to find a function $g$ that has 2 zeros in the unit disk and:

$$|f(z)- g(z)| < |f(z)|+|g(z)| \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{D}  \quad \text{(1)}$$

However, I couldn't find  such function.

I tried $g(z) = 3z^4+9z^3+10$. This function has $2$ zeros  in the unit disk according to  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3z%5E4%2B%209z%5E3%2B10%20%3D0). I wasn't able to prove $(1)$ and that $g$ has 
$2$ zeros  in the unit disk  with an analytical method.

I did the same for the function $g(z) = z^5+9z^3+10$ that has two zeros in unit disk by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E5%20%2B%209z%5E3%2B10%20%3D0). It didn't work either.

Could somebody help out to prove that $f$ has $2$ zeros in the unit disk?

Comment: tough problem.  Working on it using $g(z) = (z+3/2+8i/3)(z+3/2-8i/3)(z+9/8)(z-9/16+7i/9)(z-9/16+7i/9)$ which seems to work but its hard to show it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but given $|z| = 1$, then $\bar{z} = \frac{1}{z}$, and $z \neq 0$. So if $z^5 + 3z^4 + 9z^3 + 10 = 0$, then $\frac{1}{z^5} + \frac{3}{z^4} + \frac{9}{z^3} + 10 = 0$, so $z$ is also a root of $1 + 3z + 9z^2 + 10z^5$. It is then a root of the gcd of those two polynomials, but wolfram says it's gcd is 1, so someone is wrong here.

Comment: Easy problem if you understand complex analysis. Easier than Rouche's is the argument principle. Take that unit circle, which is hard to do additions, and map it to, say the imaginary axis.

Comment: My proposed $g(z)$ fails the condition by a tiny amount at $z = \frac{29}{30}e^{\frac{3\pi}{10}}$.

Comment: Do what I said. After the change of variable you end up with the equivalent problem of: How many times does $(880z^4-392z^2+23)+z(96z^4-912z^2+54)i$ winds around the origin when $z$ moves along the reals? Notice that that is just baby work. Since all that matters is when the real part and imaginary part change signs, and they are quadratic polynomials on z^2.

Comment: Notice that this technique shows that this type of problems can be solved by an algorithm (in a finite number of steps). For higher degrees we would need to start using Sturm's theorem to count changes of sign. So, this kind of problems belongs in the category of taking derivatives of elementary functions, or finding GCD of polynomials, etc.

Comment: This is a near duplicate.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2038467/254075

Comment: @sharding4 Pretty solution. But after using it one would still need to count out the root between the two circles to solve this problem.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Could you post your suggestion as an answer with a little more application?

Comment: @SahibaArora what does it mean "more application"? Do you mean the solution for arbitrary polynomials?

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Sorry, long day. I meant more "explanation".

Comment: @SahibaArora Let me try.

Comment: @SahibaArora ok. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: It is unfortunate that so many students get failed over the years due to not being able to solve essentially the same problem with different coefficients. I see that more as a failure of the instructors.

Comment: And it is amusing when people that are supposed to have experience also fail to solve them. But it is still a failure of their instructor.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Comments are suppose to address the post (which you did some comments above).  Please using the comment sections for ranting and similar practices that do not contribute to the site.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza I find your argument convincing; but what you've shown is that there aren't any roots along the unit circle.

Comment: @JonathanY. Yeah, I thought that could be the case.. but Wolfram found some roots pretty close to the unit circle by a numerical method ($|z| \approx 0.97$), so I'm in doubt here. I've done the gcd myself too, check if it was right, and found that they are coprime as well.

Comment: @JonathanY. maybe "in the unit disk" means "inside the unit disk"? Then it may be true, given that result from the numerical method.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza Yes, the unit disc is the open domain $|z|<1$; it's boundary is the unit circle $|z|=1$. That $f$ doesn't vanish along the unit circle is at the basis of the attempts to use Rouche's theorem, here.

Comment: @JonathanY. Oh, I see now. I was thinking on the boundary all this time and misunderstood the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technique to solve the more general problem of counting the number of zeros of a polynomial inside the unit circle. One could use it for other curves other than the circle. All is needed is to be able to map it to a line by a rational function.

The idea is to use the argument principle instead: The number of zeros of a polynomial lying inside a loop is the number of times the image of that loop by the polynomial winds around the origin. But the unit circle is hard on additions. That is why a pretty proof by Rouche's can be tricky sometimes.

Let's instead map the unit circle to the imaginary line.

You might know a rational function that does the map, but we can derive it step by step.

1. Translate the circle one unit to the right. $z= x-1$.
2. Then we do inversion. Inversion would be $x = 1/\overline{y}$. But since the coefficients are real the conjugate won't matter. So we do $x=1/y$. We get a rational function of which we only care about the numerator (a polynomial). If zero is a solution, then $-1$ was a solution of the original polynomial and that we should've tested before hand. After this the circle got mapped to the vertical line passing through (1/2,0).
3. Finally we translate to the left by 1/2. y = w+1/2.

So, we get some polynomial with real coefficients. Let's evaluate it at $w = ir$ with $r$ real.

Now, separate imaginary part and real part. Both a polynomials of smaller degree. For this particular problem I think we get 
$$(880r^4-392r^2+23)+r(96r^4-912r^2+54)i$$

Now, to determine the number of times this winds around the origin we just need to see how it jumps from quadrant to quadrant. The counting of roots (no need of precise determination) can be done with Sturm's theorem in general.

For this particular problem the work is much easier. For $r=0$ we are at the point (23,0). The polynomials $880r^4-392r^2+23$ and $96r^4-912r^2+54$ are just quadratics in disguise. One can compute the roots if so inclined.

But all it matters is their relative position, which I think it is $ABBAABBA$, where the $A$'s represent roots from the second polynomial and the $B$'s represent the roots of the first one. Take into account the factor $r$ in the imaginary part which also changes its sign when $r$ crosses zero.

That order of the roots tells you the sign of the imaginary part and real part on each of the intervals between the roots. This tells you to which quadrant the whole expression is moving. From the succession of quadrants you count the winding number and that is your number.

Comment: "For this particular problem I think we get..." -- why not show your process?

Comment: @JonathanY. Because anyone having to deal with this problem in complex analysis I assume is able to add and multiply polynomials. Also, the process is steps 1 to 3. Do you need help with that?

Comment: @JonathanY. Also the most important part of the answer is not the computation or even solving this particular problem, but to show how to solve it for any polynomial.

Comment: You'll note (a) I haven't asked the question, and (b) even though the question is currently highly rated, the answer hasn't been voted on. I therefore make suggestions to improve it: show your work, don't tell us about it. That includes explicitly composing $f$ with the mapping you used (a Mobius transform? Why go through this process?), and working out the order of roots of both polynomials you derived.

Comment: @JonathanY. I don't care about votes. And if you care so much, anyone can edit an answer. You can do it. Or post your own. And I will tell "us" whatever I decide I want to tell.